# GCP MQL query: getting metrics/minute

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-monitoring, monitoring-query-language

This query gives me metrics/sec:

```
fetch https_lb_rule::loadbalancing.googleapis.com/https/request_count
                | within 5m
                | align rate(1m)
                | every 1m
                | group_by
                    [ metric.cache_result,metric.proxy_continent,metric.response_code_class,metric.response_code,metric.protocol,resource.backend_name,resource.backend_type,resource.backend_scope,resource.backend_scope_type,resource.backend_target_type,resource.backend_target_name,resource.forwarding_rule_name,resource.matched_url_path_rule,resource.target_proxy_name,resource.url_map_name,resource.region,resource.project_id ],
                    [value_request_count_aggregate: aggregate(value.request_count)]
```

How to get metrics/minute?

Comment: does this page with examples of ratio calculation help you achieve what you want ? https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/mql/examples#qlx-ratios

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The units for the metric are `"1"` (as they are for most counter metrics).  The rate aligner result are always per-second.  So the output of the aligner has units `"1/s"`.  MQL has a [`scale`](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/mql/reference#scale-func)[
function that can be used to scale a value.  In this case, adding `| value scale(val(), "1/min")` after the align step can be used to scale this to have units "1/min".  (A [shortcut](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/mql/reference#shortcuts) way of saying that is `| scale "1/min"`)

A variation on this is to replace the `"1"` with an annotation of the thing being counted:  `"{requests}/min".  The [units](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/mql/reference#units-of-measure) are given according to the UCUM units standard

The query is then

```
fetch https_lb_rule::loadbalancing.googleapis.com/https/request_count
                | align rate(1m)
                | scale "{requests}/min"
                | every 1m
                | group_by
                    [metric.cache_result,metric.proxy_continent,
                     metric.response_code_class,metric.response_code,
                     metric.protocol,resource.backend_name,
                     resource.backend_type,resource.backend_scope,
                     resource.backend_scope_type, resource.backend_target_type,
                     resource.backend_target_name, resource.forwarding_rule_name, 
                     resource.matched_url_path_rule,
                     resource.target_proxy_name, resource.url_map_name,
                     resource.region,resource.project_id ],
                    [value_request_count_aggregate:
                       aggregate(val(0))]
                | div 60
                | within 5m
```

Final style note:  [`within`](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/mql/reference#within-tabop) gives the range of the output of the query (even if it isn't given at the end).  Putting it at the end is a good idea.

Comment: Note that `scale` requires the input to have units ("1/s" in this example) and that the units of the input have the same dimension as the desired units (inverse of time in this case).  Units can be changed arbitrarily using [`cast_units`](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/mql/reference#cast_units-func), which can be useful if you are using a metric for which units were not given.